# Can a real symmetric matrix have 0 (Zero) as one of the eigen values?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

From what I know (correct me if I am wrong):

> $0$ as an eigen value of a real symmetric matrix implies it is Singular (Non- invertible).

I am not aware of any such property with reference to real symmetric matrices.

Also, I wish to know if the following statements are correct or not.

> a)  If two matrices have the same eigenvalues, they have the same eigenvectors.  (I think it's false)
>
> b)  If two matrices have the same eigen vectors, they have the same eigen values.  (I think that's true)

Correct me.

Comment: The $1 \times 1$ matrix 0 is real, symmetric and has zero as an eigenvalue.

Comment: The zero matrix (every entries is 0) is clearly symmetric, and it has $0$ as (the only) eigenvalue. The statements a) and b) are both false.

Comment: Wow, i didn;t think of that. thanks
Comments on the secon part @copper.hat

Comment: @Capublanca can you elaborate on how both are false a bit?

Does it not come from similarity?
I am under the impression that if the eigen vectors/eigen values are same for 2 matrices, they are 'similar' too

Comment: Try the identity and a corresponding Jordan block with eigenvalues 1. Try $I$ and $2I$.

Comment: Umm.
another thing (since i cant post frequently)
**A system G is realizable if and only if the transfer matrix G(s) is a proper rational matrix.**

Out of the two statements below, which one is correct and which one is incorrect for system realizability.

        a)  All systems with proper rational transfer matrices are realizable. :  
           b)  All realizable systems have proper rational transfer matrices. :


The wordplay involved is confusing me here.  @copper.hat

Comment: Plus i did not get your Jordan part? **I** has 2 eigen values 1,1 **2I** has 2,2. That means? @copper.hat

Comment: Try them with Parts (a), (b) respectively.

Comment: Thanks!
So, What can be stated about,
"If two matrices have the same eigen values, they have the same characteristic polynomial." @copper.hat

Comment: @Heisenberg: Questions should be asked in the usual format, not as an ongoing discussion. The goal is to help many, not just one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Identify  each of the following functions from $R^2$ to $R^2$ with their matrix representations : $f(x,y)=(x,0)$ , $g(x,y)=(2 x,0)$ , $h(x,y)=(0,y)$ , $i(x,y)=((x+y)/ 2,(x+y)/2)$. Now $f,g$ have the same eigenvectors but different eigenvalues. And $h,i$ have the same eigenvalues but different eigenvectors.

Comment: Thanks!
So, What can be stated about,
"If two matrices have the same eigen values, they have the same characteristic polynomial."  @user254665

Comment: Not in 3 or more  dimensions. Every polyn. of deg n is the char. polyn. of an nxn matrix. Consider p=(x-1)(x-1)(x-2) and q=(x-1)(x-2)(x-2).The zeroes of the char. polyn. are the eigenvalues.