# If $A$ is real symmetric matrix

Tags: symmetric-matrices

If $A$ is real symmetric matrix then

a)does not contain $0$ eigenvalue

b)at least one eignvalue positive.

pick correct statement

1)option a is correct

2)option b is correct

3)both option a and b is correct

Comment: What's your choice?

Comment: i think option 3)both a and b is correct

Comment: So you think it doesn't have $0$ as an eigenvalue. In other words, you think that the matrix being real and symmetric automatically means the determinant is non-zero. This is easily shown false by, for instance, the symmetric $1\times 1$ matrix $[0]$.

Comment: @Halima.Khatun : This should help : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1469778/can-a-real-symmetric-matrix-have-0-zero-as-one-of-the-eigen-values

Comment: What is your personal involvment in the subject, besides "I think that" without any other explanation ?

Comment: Neither option (a) nor (b) is necessarily true of *all* real symmetric matrices.  First make sure you have understood definitions, then try simple examples to get a feeling for what is possible.  When you understand the possibilities, then necessity will stand out more clearly for you.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $A_1=\begin{bmatrix}{1}&{0}\\{0}&{0}\end{bmatrix},\; A_2=\begin{bmatrix}{-1}&{0}\\{0}&{-1}\end{bmatrix}.$

Comment: Why not just $-A_1$?

Comment: Of course. That is another (and optimized) option. :)